# Mongo RegEx - Match all types of space characters

Tags: regex, mongodb

`\s` regex wildcard doesn't match all types of space in mongodb (v4.0.3)

```
> db.test.insertOne({ "mail" : "special email@example.com" })
> db.test.insertOne({ "mail" : "normal email@example.com" })

> db.test.find({ mail: / / }, { _id: 0, mail: 1 })
{ "mail" : "special email@example.com" }
> db.test.find({ mail: /\s/ }, { _id: 0, mail: 1 })
{ "mail" : "normal email@example.com" }
```

The space   in `special email@example.com` above is special space, and normal space in `normal email@example.com`

Is this expected, or a bug? Is there any way to make it match all spaces?

Sidenote: I am running regex inside `$not` so I can't use `$regex`

---

**Edit**: Even `[^\S]` doesn't match both strings

```
> db.test.find({ mail: /[^\S]/ }, { _id: 0, mail: 1 })
{ "mail" : "normal email@example.com" }
```

Does mongo regex only work with ASCII?

Comment: What is your "special" space exactly? Compare the definition of `\s` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes)).

Comment: Well, `/\s/` in JS matches both the strings. `/\s/.test("special email@example.com") === /\s/.test("normal email@example.com")` is `true`

Comment: How [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) for both strings look like?

Comment: Fails for special email one with `The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range`. Normal email one gives `bm9ybWFsIGVtYWlsQGV4YW1wbGUuY29t`

Comment: `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("special email@example.com")))`
 === `"c3BlY2lhbOKAhmVtYWlsQGV4YW1wbGUuY29t"`. `escape("special email@example.com")` gives `"special%u2006email@example.com"`, `%u2006` instead of `%20` for space

Comment: Seems like mongo doesn't consider wide characters as single characters, and these regex wildcards only work on ASCII characters. Bummer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongo uses PCRE flavour https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html reads:

> The default \s characters are now HT (9), LF (10), VT (11), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32), which are defined as white space in the "C" locale. This list may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in some locales the "non-breaking space" character (\xA0) is recognized as white space, and in others the VT character is not.

You can replace `\s` with

```
[\s\x00a0\x1680\x2000\x2001\x2002\x2003\x2004\x2005\x2006
\x2007\x2008\x2009\x200a\x2028\x2029\x202f\x205f\x3000\xfeff]
```

(split for readability) for compatibility with ECMA regex flavour.

You may need to wrap codes into `{}` depending on shell/client e.g. `\x{00a0}\x{1680}` and so on.

For your query it would be:

```
db.test.find({ mail: /[\s\x{00a0}\x{1680}\x{2000}\x{2001}\x{2002}\x{2003}\x{2004}\x{2005}\x{2006}\x{2007}\x{2008}\x{2009}\x{200a}\x{2028}\x{2029}\x{202f}\x{205f}\x{3000}\x{feff}]/ }, { _id: 0, mail: 1 })
```